# Are there any sites which provide feedback for logo designs?

Tags: logo, critique

I know Behance, Dribbble etc allow designers to have feedback of their work too but their focus is mainly showcasing the work of designers.

There are sites that provide feedback of your website designs but their focus is usability.

Do we have any sites that focus on providing feedback of logo designs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Brands of the World has a critique section that does just this.

> "Post your logo to receive comments and ratings in 4 different
>   subjects: Idea, Symbol, Typography and Colors. Mark useful comments as
>   helpful to reward commenters. Post new logo version and see how
>   ratings improve."

http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/critique

Answer (score 6):

Reddit can be a bit hit or miss with these things, but it's worth a shot:

http://www.reddit.com/r/design_critiques

http://www.reddit.com/r/logo_critique

http://www.reddit.com/r/logodesign

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

In addition to other suggestions already offered, don't forget...*this site*.

To zero in on logo critiques, [search specifically for them](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logo+critique).

Also, be sure to review [guidelines for asking a great subjective question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) before posting a question to invite critiques – if you are not already familiar with them.

Answer (score 3):

If you criticize logos on here you'll just get a minus vote. Probably no one with good advice would bother because if you tell the truth people don't like it. So you will just get advice of whoever is left over who puts up with that.

So it comes down that asking the Internet what they think of your logo is like asking YouTube what they think of your video. Maybe someone knows what they're talking about, but odds are not and you'll just get a distraction.

You're the person who really cares about your logo, so learn to criticize it yourself. One good  way is to use Google Images and look at the competition: pick the best ones and worst ones. Then list the things the good ones do right, and the things the bad ones are doing wrong. Then get really mean on your work and ask why you are doing the wrong things you criticized other logos for doing. Also get mean asking why you didn't do the things that are right you pointed out.

If you ask other people to help you with critique on your logo then you are really not any further than you started. Because now instead of having to be able to figure out if your logo is good or not you have to figure out if the criticism is good or not. It's kind of like you had one problem and you want to solve it by making another harder problem.

Comment: I like that point of view, Certainly its true for many cases and i have experienced that!
Thank you for adding a really valuable answer!

Comment: It is different with people you know, don't show your logos to the whole Internet, show it to people you respect--who you know will be honest about what doesn't make sense or not. If you ask five of those people and they can't read your type or whatever, you probably screwed up.

Comment: Some (as do I) would argue that there's a big difference between criticism and critique in the context of reviewing other's work. That said, a professional designer (or artist of any sort) should have thick enough skin that when they ask for feedback, that they take it as it is. And I'd argue a good peer critique is highly valuable. Being able to critique your own work is certainly important, but so is getting quality feedback from others, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the previous answers, there is [**Desinion**](http://www.desinion.com/).

**You can present two variations of your logo design along with a question and members can vote accordingly**. An example question could be something like: *"Which variation communicates _______ more effectively?"*

Comment: i knew about this site ages ago. used it once. forgot about it. forgot the name of it. tried googling 'vote for a or b graphic design' / 'binary vote graphic design'. thank god i checked this thread.