# Critique Request: Improving logo for a Steam Group

Tags: logo, 3d, critique, design-principles

[image: The current (old) Fixed Cam Appreciation Society logo]
Hey folks - can I get some critique, suggestions? I'm looking to rework my logo for the [Fixed Camera Appreciation Society](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/fixedcamera) group on Steam, aiming to improve

- clarity/readability,
- cohesion and
- overall attractiveness,

while roughly retaining the original idea / design (a person looking up at a camera viewfinder and expressing their appreciation with a heart symbol).

Ideally this would still be in 3D or be derived from a 3D model as that relates to the topic of the group and also facilitates building an animated intro that resolves into the logo.

I am NOT a professional graphic designer. This question posted here after reading [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35605/are-there-any-sites-which-provide-feedback-for-logo-designs).

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. I'm *not* the audience, but it's overall dark, muddled and morose in nature. Perhaps that's what you like about it? What aspects are you asking for a critique on? I like the concept, but the image you've posted isn't really "clear" or highly "readable" although the concept can be discerned. Again, perhaps that helps it fit into the Steam communities - I wouldn't know. It's not so much a "logo" as it is perhaps a pictogram.

Comment: If I simply do a  [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=steam+group+logos&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIn630nYX1AhWeDjQIHW_zDIIQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1678&bih=1096&dpr=1.1) for "Steam group logos" I see that most of them are far more iconic in nature.

Comment: @Scott That doesn't really show group images for me. A better search would be [on Steam itself](https://steamcommunity.com/search/groups#text=society) (search any phrase). They tend to be photographs modified in a program like Photoshop

Comment: Folks, I appreciate your feedback and acknowledge that perhaps this material is underbaked for logo critique, where I'm probably really asking about composition at this point. With that in mind, I'll delete this question shortly. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do not delete it. Probably edit a bit to make it more precise.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome.

My first critique would be that that is not a logo, That is an illustration.

It has some potential

- The overall shape of the character looks original
- The heart indicates some fandom
- It has a 3d person look

I understand the premise is for 3D games, but you can have 3D games with a toon shader, that can be better translated into a logo.

Try to vectorize it by hand and see where it can go. Then find a specific font for the society. Ficapso has some potential as a word.

Comment: While I agree with the premise, the suggestions don't really fit the use case of Steam groups as well as perhaps other places

Comment: Folks, I appreciate your feedback and acknowledge that perhaps this material is underbaked for logo critique, where I'm probably really asking about composition at this point. With that in mind, I'll delete this question shortly. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @ReverendSpeed - you can't actually delete a question after it has been answered.  Better to probably [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/155328/edit) - give us more details, what you think might be wrong with it, possibly some alternatives you have considered/tried. I feel currently the design is too dark - makes me want to turn a light on.